# jQuery Form Plugin and jQuery Validate

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

Trying to use the the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form) and [jQuery Validate plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) together, but the form will submit with AJAX even if the required fields are blank. Here is my code:

```
// prepare the form when the DOM is ready 
$(document).ready(function() { 

     // bind form using ajaxForm 
     $('#contact-form').ajaxForm({ 
    // target identifies the element(s) to update with the server response 
    target: '#ajax-success', 

    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
    // has been received; here we apply a fade-in effect to the new content 
    success: function() { 
        $('#contact-form-wrapper').hide();
        $('#ajax-success').fadeIn('slow'); 
    } 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Ok - sorry, kinda new to using Stack Overflow. Will start accepting. I'm just trying to figure out where to drop in submitHandler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for the validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) shows how to do this.

Look at the `submitHandler` function.

Comment: But I'm using .ajaxForm and not .ajaxSubmit ... how would this work differently?

Comment: I think the idea is to use `ajaxSubmit`.  From the author who links to [the Form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) in the documentation: **The right place to submit a form via Ajax after it validated.**